# Prove that for all values of $\lambda$ and $\mu,$ the two planes intersect on the same line.

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, 3d

Prove that for all values of $\lambda$ and $\mu,$ the planes $\frac{2x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{2z}{c}-1+\lambda(\frac{x}{a}-\frac{2y}{b}-\frac{z}{c}-2)=0$ and $\frac{4x}{a}-\frac{3y}{b}-5+\mu(\frac{5y}{b}+\frac{4z}{c}+3)=0$ intersect on the same line.

---

I have no idea how to prove this question.I can see that the first plane and the second plane both are a family of planes.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal to the first plane is $$\left({2+\lambda\over a}, {1-2\lambda\over b}, {2-\lambda\over c}\right)$$

The normal to the second plane is $$\left({4\over a},{5u-3\over b},{4u\over c}\right)$$

The cross product of normals is $$\left({-3\lambda u-3\lambda-6u+6\over bc},{-4\lambda u-4\lambda - 8u+8\over ca},{5\lambda u+5\lambda+10u-10\over ab}\right)$$

which is $$(\lambda u+\lambda+2u-2)\left({-3\over bc},{-4\over ca},{5\over ab}\right)$$

Also, since both planes pass through point $(-a,-3b,3c)$ so the equation of the intersection is $$(-a,-3b,3c)+k\left({-3\over bc},{-4\over ca},{5\over ab}\right)$$

Comment: What is $k$ here?Is $k=\lambda u+\lambda+2u-2?$@croo1

Comment: It is just any multiplier. Remember a line has equation of form $v_0+t\vec{v}$. Probably I should use letter $t$ instead of $k$ but you should get the concept.

Comment: The term $(\lambda u+\lambda+2u-2)$ does not matter. For example $(1,2,3)+t(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2,3)+t(u,u,u)$ represent the same line no matter what $u$ is.

Comment: How do you find the common point of both the plane $(-a,-3b,3c)?$You guessed it or there was some insight?

Comment: Just consider ${x\over a}, {y\over b}, {z\over c}$ as a whole, say let them be $m,n,p$ and solve for $m-2n-p=2,5n+4p=-3,2m+n+2p=1,4m-3n=5$. (If there exist no solution then the proposition is wrong. In our case there exist infinite solution which is any point on the line)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You have two family of planes

$$P_1+\lambda P_2=0$$

$$P_3+\mu P_4=0$$

The direction of line of intersection of $P_1$ and $P_2$ is along $\vec{n_1}\times \vec{n_2}$ where $\vec{n_1}$, $\vec{n_2}$ are normal vectors to $P_1$ and $P_2$ Respectively.

Similarly find line of intersection of $P_3$ and $P_4$. Observe whether both the lines have same direction.

Comment: Yes both the lines of intersection of $P_1,P_2$ and $P_3,P_4$ are parallel,but the question says they $P_1+\lambda P_2=0$ and $P_3+\mu P_4=0$ intersect in the same line.How to prove that?@Ekaveera Kumar Sharma.